# How to query createdby, modifiedby from user table and SQL Self Joins

Tags: sql, join

I am novice to sql and exploring. I have 4 tables from same schema - Account,Contact, Accountcontactrelation and user
I have below query,

```
SELECT acnt.cusrid, 
       acnt.createdbyid, 
       acnt.lastmodifiedbyid, 
       acr.createdbyid, 
       acr.lastmodifiedbyid, 
       con.createdbyid, 
       con.lastmodifiedbyid 
FROM   (SELECT * 
        FROM   accountcontactrelation) acr 
       JOIN (SELECT * 
             FROM   account) acnt 
         ON ( acnt.id = acr.accountid ) 
       JOIN (SELECT * 
             FROM   contact) con 
         ON con.id = acr.contactid
```

how do I join user table to get the user names from the user table instead of ids for

```
acnt.createdbyid, 
       acnt.lastmodifiedbyid, 
       acr.createdbyid, 
       acr.lastmodifiedbyid, 
       con.createdbyid, 
       con.lastmodifiedbyid
```

do I use user table with self join ?If so how can I do that?Any guidance is much appreciated.Thanks

Comment: You should add your sample data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your `user` table has columns `Id` & `Username`, you can just join each column that references the user is as below.

```
SELECT acnt.cusrid,     
    acnt.createdbyid, 
    acnt.lastmodifiedbyid, 
    acr.createdbyid, 
    acr.lastmodifiedbyid, 
    con.createdbyid,
    con.lastmodifiedbyid 

    -- Add username columns
    acntCreatedbyUser.username,
    acntLastmodifiedbyUser.username,
    acrCreatedbyUser.username,
    acrLastmodifiedbyUser.username,
    conCreatedbyUser.username,
    conLastmodifiedbyUser.username,

FROM accountcontactrelation acr 
JOIN account acnt ON acnt.id = acr.accountid
JOIN contact con ON con.id = acr.contactid

-- Join user table to each column that has user id to get username
JOIN user acntCreatedbyUser ON user.id = acnt.createdbyid
JOIN user acntLastmodifiedbyUser ON user.id = acnt.lastmodifiedbyid
JOIN user acrCreatedbyUser ON user.id = acr.createdbyid
JOIN user acrLastmodifiedbyUser ON user.id = acr.lastmodifiedbyid
JOIN user conCreatedbyUser ON user.id = con.createdbyid
JOIN user conLastmodifiedbyUser ON user.id = con.lastmodifiedbyid
```

*Note: I've not tested the sql as there's no schema. Also I've removed the sub queries as it's not needed.*

Comment: Thanks Greg, I think we need to use the alias name of the user table in the join condition. I got the gist of it though.Thanks for your help.